# How do you solve EMS Server connection when giving an error when you test?

Tags: jms, tibco, ems, tibco-business-works

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPKyY.jpg) Hey everyone I am having a trouble connecting to the ems server, it gives me a error that goes like this "Could not connect to ems server at "tcp://"localhost:7222"...I am using TIBCO BW5.

"The attempt returned an error"

"java.land.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tibco/tibjms/admin/TibjmsAdmin."

I would appreciate if you can tell me more about the error, and also how to fix it.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you able to ping `OneConnect-PC` from the same machine where you were trying to connect? Can you try the command `telnet OneConnect-PC 7222` and show the result? What is the `tra` that you are using? Hope ems is running.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to add tibjms.jar to your bw library.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are trying to connect remote EMS Server, and you do not have EMS installed in your local machine. If that is true, copy tibjms.jar file from tibco\ems\8.2\lib  to tibco\tra\5.9\lib folder in your local machine. Then retry the domain utility.

Hope this helps to solve your problem.